# C# Connect to Docker Mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, virtual-machine

I have a Linux VM running [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgzkU.png) MySQL container.
The VM has ping to the host, and the host has ping to the VM.
I'm trying to connect to the DB through C# code on my host, but it just doesn't work.

Here's my connection string, with the actual IP instead of the text here:

```
private const string connectionString =
        "SERVER=IP ADDRESS HERE;" +
        "PORT=3306;" +
        "DATABASE=hasava_db;" +
        "UID=root;" +
        "PWD=pwd;" +
        "SslMode=None;";
```

Here's the function itself:

```
public void func()
    {
        MySqlConnection cnn;
        cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2dx2.png) error message.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, you work under windows and have a linux vm running the docker engine with currently 1 mysql container on it? If that is indeed correct you need 2 hops (docker --> linux --> windows) to be able to connect. If you start the mysql docker container by binding the port to the linux localhost you could try forwarding that to windows. So docker 3306 to linux 3306. Then the VM should open port 3306 to be accessable for the windows host (if you run virtualbox, check for port forwarding under network settings).

Comment: The problem is that on my VBox program the port forwarding option is greyed out (2 NIC: first one is host only and the second one is Bridged)

Comment: I have the exact opposite situation (linux as host, win10 as client) and when I go to networking the option is available only with the NAT network setting. But I'm willing to bet that the linux client port is blocked and you are therefore not able to connect. If able you could try shutting down the machine and seeing if your options will become available.

Comment: Now I was able to change that to the NAT NIC but still can't connect...

Comment: That might be another problem altogether. If you are using Virtualbox it's very straighforward. Just fill in a name (like mysqlfwd), a host port (for example 12345) and a guest port (3306, where your mysql service runs). That should be enough. See this image:https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F122641%2Fhow-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server%2F&psig=AOvVaw1Tk7THn41E_Kt40ljrPvPW&ust=1602840285599000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLD118GjtuwCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Comment: I tried to connect from my host to the mysql db on my linux docker engine guest through HeidiSQL and it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Which makes sense if the port forwarding is not active. Can you connect on the linux machine (perhaps commandline)? Is there a reason for you to run docker inside the linux VM instead of using the windows version? That would simplify the situation alot I presume.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: I did not get it to work. I activated the port but I still can’t connect to the DB even through HeidiSQL. The firewalls on both machines (host and guest) are disabled. Again, 2 NICs on my guest machine - NAT and Host only

Comment: Can you show us how you run the Docker machine? Also, can you try to connect commandline from the linux vm to your mysql instance?  With 2 nic's I could also imagine connecting to the wrong ip address (one will be 10.*.*.* and the other one 192.168.58.* presumably).